# Insert page title in print CSS

Tags: jquery, css, title

I need to grab the page title's on my website and then insert it into the print version of the pages. I have a seperate print.css ofcourse, but is there any way I can grab that title data, maybe as a variable using jQuery, then insert it using CSS, eg. div:before {content:"variable name goes here"} ? Or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Why not have the page title in an element in the page, and control its visibility with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure!

```
// this would be an example of how to grab the title
<script language="JavaScript">
alert(document.title);
</script>
```

My approach would be slightly different.

```
<h1 class="web-hide">the page title goes here</h1>
```

And then you would have a `.web-hide` that would be visible/not-visible depending on the print/not-print version of the page.

Comment: But how would I populate the div with the title? That code snippet just pop's up an alert with the title in it.

Comment: I'm assuming you are also controlling the page via PHP or something alike. The DIV would be populated on page creation. These are two different sollutions. I would populate the DIV interelly by PHP/ASP you can also populate it using jQuery with something like: `$('#divId').html(document.title)`

Comment: Didn't work exactly but pointed me in the right direction. Ended up doing: `$("#wrap").before("<div id=ttl>"+document.title+"</div>");
  $("#ttl").css("display","none");` in the js and then displaying block as the first comment suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just have a hidden element on your main page that gets a `display:block;` in the print CSS.